# AngularJs/Javascript target an object child thats label is a number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am hitting a back end API and the return data is an object:

```
...
stars: {
 3: 5,
 4: 3
},
...
```

Using angularJS as my frontend frame work how would I go about targeting `stars.3`? It does not seem to like that I trying to target a label that's a number.

Comment: use stars["3"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object keys are string. Try with bracket (`[]`) notation:

```
stars["3"]
```

Comment: Thanks you, once i can ill award the answer to you!